# Creating a loop menu in Java till exit

Tags: java, loops, menu, switch-statement

I'm learning Java, and I want to convert my programs from Python to Java just for learning. How can I create a loop menu till for example option "5" is selected which is "Save and exit".

This is my Python version quickly typed :

```
while True:
choice = input("1 Command 1\n2 Command 2\n3 Command 3\n4 Command 4 \n5 Exit\nEnter Command: ")

if choice =="1":
    print("Command 1")
    continue
elif choice =="2":
    print("Command 2")
    continue
elif choice =="3":
    print("Command 3")
    continue
elif choice =="4":
    print("Command 4")
    continue
elif choice =="5":
    exit = input("Press any key to exit...")
    break
else:
    break
```

And this is what I got so far with Java:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("
1.Command 1\n2.Command 2\n3.Command 3\n4.Command 4\n5.Exit\nEnter Command: ");

  String text = input.nextLine();
//----------------------------------------------------------

  switch(text) {
      case "1":
      System.out.println("command 1");
      break;

      case "2":
      System.out.println("command 2");
      break;

      case "3":
      System.out.println("command 3");
      break;

      case "4":
      System.out.println("command 4");
      break;

      case "5":
      System.out.println("command 5");
      break;

      default:
      System.out.println("Unknown command");

  }
```

Comment: you can write your code in a do while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want to wrap your code with a `while` or a `do while` loop.

as:

```
do {
 your code here

} while (!"5".equals(text));
```

Comment: Thx this really helped me out.
Now how can i def the menu for example in python i would do it like "def showMenu():"

Answer (score 0):

to exit the loop you can simply break after 5 is entered but if you would like to exit the entire program the following can be helpful

```
case "5":
  System.out.println("command 5");
  System.exit(0);
```